# destroy-method of spring bean is not getting called when my tomcat shuts down

Tags: java, spring

I am not able to find the cause why my `destroy-method` is not getting called when my application gets shut down in case of the tomcat stops.

I have a web application and the spring context is getting loaded through ContextLoaderListener in web.xml like below:

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:appContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

below is a Employee bean in my application:

**Employee.class**

```
public class Employee {
    String eName;
    long eSal;
    public String getEName() {
        return eName;
    }
    public void setEName(String name) {
        eName = name;
    }
    public long getESal() {
        return eSal;
    }
    public void setESal(long sal) {
        eSal = sal;
    }

    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Initiaizing...");
        System.out.println("eName: " + eName + " - eSal: " + eSal);
    }

    public void close() {
        System.out.println("Destroying...");
    }
}
```

and the bean is defined in my application context file like below:

**appContext.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <beans:bean id="employee" class="com.test.Employee" init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="eName" value="sandip" />
        <beans:property name="eSal" value="80000" />
    </beans:bean>        
</beans:beans>
```

Tomcat console logs:

```
May 12, 2014 11:28:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\client;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\NetSarang;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Access Connections\;D:\Project\maven-2.0.7\bin;D:\Software Backup\apache-ant-1.7.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin;D:\Project\OBD3\1.5;D:\Software Backup\CVS;D:\Project\UNIX\UnxUtils\usr\local\wbin;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;D:\Personal\MongoDB\MongoDB_work\mongodb\bin;D:\Software Installed\MariaDB 5.5\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\bin
May 12, 2014 11:28:46 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:testSpringBeanDestroy' did not find a matching property.
May 12, 2014 11:28:46 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8093
May 12, 2014 11:28:46 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 419 ms
May 12, 2014 11:28:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 12, 2014 11:28:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.32
May 12, 2014 11:28:46 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\Project\Workspace_new\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\testSpringBeanDestroy\WEB-INF\lib\servlet.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
May 12, 2014 11:28:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Initiaizing...
eName: sandip - eSal: 80000
May 12, 2014 11:28:47 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8093
May 12, 2014 11:28:47 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8011
May 12, 2014 11:28:47 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/20  config=null
May 12, 2014 11:28:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 768 ms
```

When I start my tomcat I can see that my init method is getting called but unfortunately when I stops the tomcat the close() i.e. the destroy method is not getting called.

I am using spring 3.1.2 distributions jars.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you stop the Tomcat?

Comment: just kill the process or using shutdown.sh

Comment: And you get the same behavior with both kill and shutdown.sh? I would have thought that only kill will not work as expected.

Comment: yes.. same behavior for both case.

Comment: Try to find out if ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed is called during tomcat's shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Andrei. +1 for you. 
The problem was that I was not shutting down properly. Now after reading some docs I found that if I shuts down my tomcat gracefully either from the Tomcat Manager or using the shutdown scripts like(shutdwon.sh/shutdown.bat), My destroy method is getting called.

Kill -9 command will not work and also if trying to stop from eclipse, it is not working.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation. I want my Servlet's `destroy()` method to be triggered, and be able to run to completion, when the Tomcat7 service is stopped (`service tomcat7 stop`) but I can't tell if this is the right approach. Where can you find the shutdown scripts? (`shutdown.sh/shutdown.bat`)? Should `service tomcat7 stop` be equivalent or will that not call `destroy()`

Comment: wanted to draw your attention specifically @Sandy